Time-respecting Paths in igraph
I am using igraph in R to do social network analysis (SNA). My edges represent ties or connections that happen at specific points in time - think for example of the mailing of letters - so they are (or should be) time- or date-stamped. Say I am modelling the diffusion of ideas. If A writes to B and then B writes to C, it is conceivable that B passes on an idea or opinion from A to C. In network terms, A, B and C are nodes, A->B and B->C are edges, and A->B->C is a (valid in this case) path. But if B writes to C before A's letter arrives, A, B and C are still network nodes, A->B and B->C are still edges, but A->B->C is no longer a (valid or time-respecting) path. But I cannot, I think, easily account for this temporal dimension in igraph. I cannot, for example, prevent invalid paths from being included in betweenness centrality calculations, because the igraph user has no control (that I am aware of) over how paths are computed; you specify nodes and edges, igraph does the rest. Am I right in this, or does igraph either a) allow direct input of paths calculated 'manually', or b) can igraph be instructed to calculate time-respecting paths? Thanks.
There is a package called pathpy which can do time-dependent network computations, but it for use with Python only, and it is anyways nightmarish to use - the documentation in particular is lamentable.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
